# Chrome Dev Tools: automatically turn on network recording

Tags: google-chrome, web-development

I want to have network recording already on during development of a webpage, so that when I open Chrome Dev Tools, it already has the info without having to reload.

Currently if I open the Network panel after the page is loaded it gives the message:

> ```
>                               Recording Network Activity... 
>
>                    Perform a request or hit F5 to record the reload.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The developer tools need to be open before they can record anything. It's not possible for them to start recording before they are open.

If you want to record network activity when you first visit a page:

1. open a blank tab (about:blank)
2. open the developer tools (clear previous network recordings if you want)
3. visit the page you want to record

Comment: Thanks, my question is to try to do exactly what you are saying is not possible. I don't have an actual technical problem with the current workflow; I'm looking for a setting I can change to fix my lack of foresight, and your solution would require even more foresight :D

Comment: Ok so why not just open the dev tools and leave them open?

Comment: Because I forget (and sometimes prefer to have them off to better experience the site). So ya, I guess it's a trivial question.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit. Alas this answer no longer applies to Chrome 74 or newer...**

Folks at QualityUnit posted a pretty neat workaround for this problem:

Start Chrome and type `chrome://net-internals/#events` into address bar. This turns the tab into **an event monitor** which records much of what happens in that Chrome browser, including network requests etc. As long as you launch new tabs into the same Chrome, this monitoring tab immediately has the info of the request. It records among other things details of the GET and POST request's body etc.

Source: [QualityUnit: How to read network requests in Chrome for new tab or popup window](https://support.qualityunit.com/329593-How-to-read-network-requests-in-Chrome-for-new-tab-or-popup-window)

Example: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtY3S.png)